# wpa_supplicant issues on android phone

Tags: wi-fi, connection-issues, wpa-supplicant

**Disclaimer:** My knowledge of android as well as the inner workings of wifi connections are exceedingly limited. Additionally, I'm new to stackoverflow, so I might just be the worst customer you had...

I'm having issues with my android phone (Fairphone 2). 
For some reason, I cannot connect to any new WiFi, i.e. ones I did not connect to before. The `adb logcat` shows the errors:

```
02-24 11:33:49.215  2221  3763 E WifiConfigStore: Failed to look-up a string: WPA_EAP
02-24 11:33:49.215  2221  3763 E WifiConfigStore: Failed to look-up a string: IEEE8021X
02-24 11:33:50.221 23048  7088 E WakeLock: GCM_HB_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
02-24 11:33:50.223 23048  7088 E WakeLock: GCM_CONN_ALARM release without a matched acquire!
02-24 11:33:50.857 25094 25094 E wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan0/drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast: No such file or directory
02-24 11:33:50.857 25094 25094 E wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to set IPv4 unicast in multicast filter
02-24 11:33:50.858 25094 25094 E wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan0/drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast: No such file or directory
02-24 11:33:50.858 25094 25094 E wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to set IPv4 unicast in multicast filter
02-24 11:33:50.860 25094 25094 E wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan0/drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast: No such file or directory
02-24 11:33:50.860 25094 25094 E wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Failed to set IPv4 unicast in multicast filter
```

So I was thinking: I'm missing a file. Googling 
`drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast` I found [this](https://sysctl-explorer.net/net/ipv4/drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast/) webpage, so I tried to push a file of that name to the `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/wlan0/` folder, but I cannot do that since my phone is not rooted.
Interestingly, I found out this morning that I can connect to the open (unencrypted) wifi at my university.
My Android version is 7.1.2

I have literally no idea what is going on, so any help would be much appreciated, especially since I reset all my network settings (before I knew the issue is related to new WiFi connections in general, not just the new one I got at home), so now ALL WiFi networks are new to my phone.

Thanks a bunch in advance

*Edit:* Added some more of the error log

Comment: The missing `drop_unicast_in_l2_multicast` file should not stop you from connecting to all WiFi connections. Neither you can add that by pushing, even with root. It's a recent addition to Linux kernel. Android kernel is usually older on most of the devices currently in-use. Look for other error messages in log.

Comment: Thanks @IrfanLatif, I have added some more lines of the error message

Comment: Nothing evident from log. Just that there are some issues with authentication. May be a factory reset fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks again. I found this [bug report](https://bugtracker.fairphone.com/project/fairphone-android-7/issue/87), which suggests that it might be a fairphone specific issue. Some people report solving the issue when setting their wifi to WPA, but that seems unwise to me. Also, it seems here that a factory reset does not help. Nonetheless, I will attempt that as well